# Flask not reporting about url_for errors in templates and gets stuck

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm developing my first app in python and it looks like something is wrong with my configuration. If there's an error in jinja template app says nothing and basically hangs up.

Here's my minimal example:

./example.py:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return flask.render_template('example.html');
```

./templates/example.html:

```
<html>
  {{ url_for('example', filename='doesnt.matter') }}
  this page will never render, RIP
</html>
```

./start.sh: `FLASK_APP=example.py FLASK_ENV=development flask run`

So when I run flask and go to localhost - request gets stuck and I never get any response. Also the whole server becomes unresponsive and I'm forced to restart it.

#### Environment:

- Python version: 3.6.5
- Flask version: 1.1.1

I'm on win7x64 mingw under venv, however when I launch via windows command prompt this behavior continues

console looks like this:

```
 * Serving Flask app "example.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 253-384-519
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Also I suppose it's not only about url_for and rather it goes for any error in the render_template function

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, it's weird. I notice there is an unnecessary `;` at the end of your code, maybe you can try to remove it.

Comment: @GreyLi did you try to reproduce it exactly in python 3.6.5 or some other version?

Comment: I forgot, sorry :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in python version. I updated it to the latest (3.8.5) and problem disappeared.